# VSCode does not use conda environment when starting from the terminal

Tags: python, macos, visual-studio-code, conda

I'm using Visual Studio Code (VSCode) to do some Python programming on a Mac. I use conda for my Python environments. When I open a folder from within VSCode (using File -> Open... from the menu), it opens the selected folder of Python files. I select a Python file to edit it and VSCode selects my default conda environment which is named `base`. When I open the integrated VSCode terminal, it also uses the `base` conda environment. A screen capture of this process is shown below.

[image: screen capture working example]

I can also start VSCode from the macOS terminal using the `code` command. From within the Mac terminal, I `cd` to the folder containing the Python files. From within the directory, I open VSCode using the `code .` terminal command. I select a Python file to edit it and VSCode selects my default conda environment which is named `base`. When I open the integrated VSCode terminal, it says I'm using the `base` conda environment. However, the integrated VSCode terminal is not using conda environment Python and packages. A screen capture of this is shown below.

[image: screen capture of nonworking example]

My VSCode settings are:

```json
{
    "telemetry.telemetryLevel": "off",
    "python.condaPath": "/opt/miniconda3/bin/conda",
    "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "/opt/miniconda3/bin/python",
    "python.pythonPath": "/opt/miniconda3/bin/python",
    "python.terminal.activateEnvInCurrentTerminal": true,
    "python.terminal.activateEnvironment": true,
    "python.linting.flake8Args": [
        "--max-line-length=120"
    ],
    "breadcrumbs.enabled": false,
    "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.osx": "zsh",
    "terminal.explorerKind": "external",
    "terminal.integrated.inheritEnv": false,
    "python.linting.flake8Enabled": true,
    "editor.fontSize": 13,
    "terminal.integrated.fontSize": 13,
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Dracula Soft",
}
```

How can I make the integrated VSCode terminal use the default conda environment when the app is started from the macOS terminal?

Comment: Do you reopen the folder which has been selected the base conda environment or do you open a new folder?

Comment: And what's the meaning of `open the integrated VSCode terminal which says the conda environment is active`. Could you provide a screenshot of it? thanks.

Comment: Is there not a canonical answer for this? I feel like I see a "Conda not working in VSC terminal" question once a week. Someone please ping me if you have a duplicate proposal.

Comment: @merv There are many conda related questions about VSCode but I have not seen any questions regarding this particular issue.

Comment: @wigging It looks very weird. In the `code .` route, if you create a new terminal what will happen? If you activate the anaconda manually what will happen?

Comment: @Steven-MSFT Using the `code .` approach, I still have the same problem as mentioned in my question even if I create a new terminal and/or if I manually activate the conda environment.

Comment: If you switch to some other python interpreter, does it work? and the switch back to conda base? It's really weird.

Comment: @Steven-MSFT Nope, that does not work. No matter what I do, the integrated VSCode terminal uses the system Python when the VSCode app is started with `code .`.

Comment: Is this a bug in Visual Studio Code?

Comment: @wigging So sorry for being late, I am on a weekend, so have not responded to you.  From your description, it's really weird, I have no mac, so it's hard to submit a bug by myself, could you submit a bug on the [vscode-python](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues)? Thanks.

Comment: Can you get the python interpreter list in the command palette?

Comment: @Steven-MSFT Yes, when I use the command palette it lists the Python interpreters associated with the various conda environments on my computer. Also, I submitted my question as an issue on the vscode-python repo on GitHub.

Comment: @Steven-MSFT I submitted an issue https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/17960. Apparently it's a feature request since this capability does not currently exist in VS Code.

Comment: @wigging I think he misunderstands you.

Answer (score 3):

Not a mac user, but I recently had to sort through a similar issue with vscode on Windows. It would not handle conda environments correctly until I added

```
"python.condaPath": "C:\\Users\\xxxx\\mambaforge\\Scripts\\conda.exe"
```

(Note for other Windows users: I also switched the default terminal to Command Prompt since conda and Powershell don't play perfectly well together)

I see that you have this variable in your settings file, but you're only leading the camel to water (/opt/miniconda3/bin/conda) not shoving its face into the bucket (/opt/miniconda3/bin/conda/Scripts/conda.exe, I presume), so give that a try. I know that the approach you are currently using did not resolve my issue until I pointed right at conda.exe in the Scripts folder (where the activation bat lives).

Another note to consider: I didn't set any of these lines in my settings.json (with one exception, noted):

```
{
    "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "/opt/miniconda3/bin/python",
    "python.pythonPath": "/opt/miniconda3/bin/python",
    "python.terminal.activateEnvInCurrentTerminal": true,
    "python.terminal.activateEnvironment": true,
    "python.linting.flake8Args": [
        "--max-line-length=120"
    ],
    "breadcrumbs.enabled": false,
    "terminal.explorerKind": "external",
    "terminal.integrated.inheritEnv": false, // <-- I actually have this set to 'true'
    "python.linting.flake8Enabled": true,
}
```

Not that any of these are necessarily coming into play here at all, just wanted to throw it out there in case it helps.

Comment: actually just ran into a nightmare issue, that was completely related to `terminal.integrated.inheritEnv` being set(by my past self) to `FALSE`; pytest was failing when my routines worked fine literally everywhere else. Turning it back to `true` instantly solved the issue. bashrc was being sourced the same, all environment vars the same, same python instance etc; made no sense. LEAVE THIS SET TO TRUE!

Answer (score 1):

In the command palette of VS Code, use `> Python: Select Interpreter` and select the version of python you want to use.

Once you select, it should be set as default, so that should be what you need.

To activate the environment in the integrated terminal, ensure that the setting `python.terminal.activateEnvironment` in VS Code is set to true.

Source: [Visual Studio Code Documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_select-and-activate-an-environment)

Comment: I added my VSCode settings to the question. I already have `python.terminal.activateEnvironment` enabled.